# How to add a really tiny placemark to a KML file - to create heatmap

Tags: heatmap, data-analysis, kml

How can I add a really small placemark to KML file? - a tiny dot or something similar.

I have set of positions (latitude and longitude) that I can add to a KML file to create a 'heatmap'. I'm adding each position as a placemark, as I add more and positions to the file I can build up a heatmap showing cluster of positions and density.

The problem is that the icons (for example the default yellow pin) are simply too large. Is there any way to add a single dot or tiny marker? just a couple of pixels across would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?:

[image: measle.png]

KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
  <Document>
    <Style id="measle">
<IconStyle id="measle">
  <!-- specific to IconStyle -->
  <scale>1</scale>
  <Icon>
    <href>https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png</href>
  </Icon>
  <hotSpot x="0.5"  y="0.5"
    xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
</IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark id="pm123">
      <styleUrl>#measle</styleUrl>
      <name>point123</name>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>-95.44,40.42,0</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark id="pm456">
      <styleUrl>#measle</styleUrl>
      <name>point456</name>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>-95.43,40.42,0</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

[image: screenshot of Google Map]

[example showing on a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map with KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/MeasleIcons.kml)